# Operadores sobrecargados

Tags: sobrecarga-de-operadores

Debo crear una clase que obtenga los atributos nombre y edad por parte del usuario, no se si sea recomendable hacer esto en el constructor; la idea principal es obtener por medio de operadores sobrecargados la edad promedio de al menos 2 registros, tengo un boceto de como creo que es esto, pero no estoy seguro.
Al crear el objeto como quiero datos que ingrese el usuario llamo al método datos, pero creo espera que le asigne al objeto los datos; el error es este "no matching function for call to ‘alumno::alumno()’"

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;
class alumno
{
    private:            // Atributos
        string nombre;
        float edad;
        
    public:             // Métodos
        alumno(string, float);                  // Constructor
        void muestrain();
        void datos();
        alumno operator+()
        {
            nombre = nombre;
            edad = edad*2;
        }
};
alumno::alumno(string _nombre, float _edad)       // Constructor
{
    nombre = _nombre;
    edad = _edad;
}
void alumno :: datos()
{
    cout << " escriba su nombre  \n ";
    cin  >> nombre;
    
    cout << " escriba su edad    \n ";
    cin >> edad;
}

void alumno :: muestrain()
{
    cout << "nombre = " << nombre << "\n";
    cout << "edad = " << edad << "\n";
}

int main()
{
    alumno estudiante;
    estudiante.datos();
    estudiante.muestrain();
    +estudiante;
    estudiante.muestrain();
    
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Cuál es el error?

Comment: bueno primero no se si todo este bien, supongo que para crear mas de un objeto tendre que declararlo en el main, pero en el unico que tengo, el error es este "no matching function for call to ‘alumno::alumno()’"

Comment: Las funciones están fuera de la clase.